# no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer rails 5.2.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried using retrofit2 to post to rails to filter some data from `places` params[:filter] are are:

```
[
    {
        "id"=>2,
        "name"=>"Cafe",
        "service_code"=>0
    },
    {
        "id"=>3,
        "name"=>"restaurant",
        "service_code"=>0
    }
]
```

so I wanted to get the id, with a simple params[:filter][:id] but it returns 
`no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`
thanks for the help and sorry if it seems like a simple problem

Comment: How about `params[:filter][0]['id']`? Since `params[:filter]` is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)

This is error is raised in this case because you're trying to access to the elements in an array as it'd be a hash. Ruby tries to convert the symbol you're passing as parameter to the `[]` method, because the receiver is an array, and arrays can be accessed to their elements by their index.

In short, you have an array of hashes, if you need the id from one of them, filter the elements until you get it and there you can use `['id']`:

```
[{ "id"=>2, "name"=>"Cafe", "service_code"=>0 },
 { "id"=>3, "name"=>"restaurant", "service_code"=>0 }][0]['id']
# 2
```

Comment: i got lost at `as it'd be a hash`

Comment: @WEBjuju; `{foo: 1}[:foo] # => 1` while `[1][:foo] # => TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)`